# Make Print From Textbox stay in paper margins? (w/PageSetup)

Tags: vb.net

I've been having lots of problems getting the print dialog and page set up to work together to print text from a textbox, ive spent hours doing research and trying everything, I cannot get it to work, can someone please help me, and give me the code to print a document from a textbox and also get page set up to work with it (just like in notepad)

Here is my code thats not working

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    PageSetupDialog1.ShowDialog()
    PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings = PageSetupDialog1.PageSettings
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim textArea As New Rectangle()
    e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox1.Text, TextBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, 100, 100)
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `PrintDocument` you can draw text to a `Rectangle` and it will wrap naturally. You can also employ a [StringFormat](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.drawing.stringformat(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=D7FCVNXhKIStyATS9YH4AQ&usg=AFQjCNGkspjX0usqVC_HKmP_lvibDdOGjw&sig2=MUZPcQVch7OgNqyiVue1hg&bvm=bv.77648437,d.aWw) object for other formatting help.

```
Private Sub printDoc_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal ev As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles printDoc.PrintPage
  Dim textArea As New Rectangle(e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height)
  e.Graphics.DrawString(textbox1.Text, New Font("Consolas", 10), Brushes.Navy, textArea)
 'other stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried that, can you help me setup the code thats where im messing up on, also the page setup as well please thanks

Comment: Mine is just totally wrong, basically there is 1 textbox, print setup dialog, print document print dialog, and 2 buttons, one that says print and one that says setup, can you help me set it up from scratch?

Comment: Come on at least show your attempt, or it feels like we are just your code writing service - which we are not.

Comment: Ok i added my attempt

Comment: Check out how I define the Rectangle. Also note which overload we are using for the DrawString method - it takes the Rectangle as a parameter so it knows where to print to.

Comment: I've tried too many things, to the point where I broke the letter "p" on now what is my old keyboard. Can you please help, I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect and very simple solution to keep all text on the page; works perfectly.
Private Sub printDoc_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal ev As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles printDoc.PrintPage Dim textArea As New Rectangle(e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height) e.Graphics.DrawString(textbox1.Text, New Font("Consolas", 10), Brushes.Navy, textArea) 'other stuff End Sub

Comment: Consider using code blocks to make your answer easier to read.